# How to calculate Rank from mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql rank function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function)

I have the following table in MySQL:

```
===================================================================
id  | member|  total_correct_question | time_taken_in_seconds |

===================================================================
1   |  abc  |     2                    |       4              |
2   |  def  |     3                    |       6              |
3   |  ghi  |     3                    |       4              |
4   |  jkl  |     3                    |       5              |
====================================================================
```

I want to show the rank of each user from mysql query. Can any one suggest me a query for this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is a very common question. Please take a minute to search the archives first before posting. Often a question was asked and answered already - often several times over.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS rank,a.*
  FROM
      (SELECT * 
       FROM   Your_table  
       ORDER BY total_correct_question DESC,
                time_taken_in_seconds)a,(SELECT @i:=0) r
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9354a/1)

Comment: Wooow...,Its Working Fine Thanks... john

Answer (score 1):

You can create a subquery which produces cartesian product from the original query and the most interesting is that you can increment it by one (*which then result to it RANK Number*).

```
SELECT    @rankNo:=@rankNo+1 RankNo,
          a.*
FROM      Table1 a, (SELECT @rankNo:=0) r 
ORDER BY `total_correct_question` DESC,
         `time_taken_in_seconds` ASC
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6343b/6)

Comment: Wooow...,Its Working Fine Thanks... john