# select all data with position of given id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my table

```
   id   |   name   |  userid  |  score  |      date      |
   ------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |   john   |    1     |   44    |  2013-03-2 
    2   |   mary   |    2     |   59    |  2013-03-5  
    3   |   john   |    12    |   38    |  2013-03-8 
    4   |   elvis  |    3     |   19    |  2013-02-10 
    5   |   john   |    11    |   1002  |  2013-01-11
    6   |   johnah |    10    |   200   |  2013-01-11
```

I want to show number of position of my given userid order by highest score.

if i give userid 12 in my query then it show position number 5 for user 12 depend on highest score

Comment: I see it position 5 based on the data you provided

Comment: Select all records from the database and use `ORDER BY score`. Then loop through the results and search for the given user ID. Count how many times the loop was entered before the user ID was found and you got your result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541040/how-to-calculate-rank-from-mysql-table

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM table_name WHERE userid!=12 AND 
score>(SELECT score FROM table_name WHERE userid=12);
```

Comment: if i give userid 12 in my query then it show position number 5 for user 12 depend on highest score

Comment: Isn't this what you want? I mean this query should work for you @user3484136

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
SELECT *  
FROM table_name 
WHERE id =(SELECT max( userid ) FROM table_name)
```